# filter() in function is affecting another

Tags: javascript, angular

In the below, I have a function that should be filtering `accountView`, but for some reason it's also filtering `accountCompare`. Not sure why this is happening. I thought I had assigned the two seperately so that accountCompare is always a constant.

```
getAccount() {
    this.accounts.getAccount(this.accountId).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.accountView = this.apiHandler.responseHandler(response);
            this.accountCompare = this.apiHandler.responseHandler(response);
            console.log(this.accountCompare);
        },
        (err) => {
            this.apiHandler.errorHandler(err);
        }
    );
}

//then in this function, I filter accountView, however it appears to also be affecting accountCompare as well.

userDelete(id) {
    if (this.accountCompare.users.some(item => item.id === id)) {
        this.accountForm.value.usersToDelete.push(id);
    }
    this.accountView.users = this.accountView.users.filter(user => user.id !== id);
    /* this.accountForm.value.usersToAdd = this.accountForm.value.usersToAdd.filter(user => id !== id); */
    console.log(this.accountCompare);

}
```

Comment: Probably what's happening is that those calls to `this.apiHandler.respoonseHandler()` return a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-primitive values are passed by reference. This means you are actually updating a reference, not a value.

A quick hack for you :

```js
this.accountView = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.apiHandler.responseHandler(response)));
this.accountCompare = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.apiHandler.responseHandler(response)));
```

Comment: you should explain what this quick hack does. Maybe OP (or future readers) will actually want to keep the reference to the original object

Comment: I explained how it works. This hacks creates a string from an object, then parses this string to create a new object.

Comment: Umm, I think the value is passed rather than a reference and it's being reference/pointed by another variable or object.

Comment: `this.apiHandler.responseHandler(response)` seems like a custom function, I think it edits the responses (adding fields and such) and returns it. If so, this is by reference. Anyway, simply test this hack to see if it works !

Comment: it worked. and yes `this.apiHandler.responseHandler(response)` is a seperate method that sends the response through an exception handler that are server sends when there is a ss error. so if it passes it returns a payload.